# How can I test the method called in the completion handler of a UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, uialertcontroller, xctestcase

I have a protocol I attach to a `UIViewController` that I would like to allow the presentation of a `UIAlertController`.

```
import UIKit

struct AlertableAction {
    var title: String
    var style: UIAlertAction.Style
    var result: Bool
}

protocol Alertable {
    func presentAlert(title: String?, message: String?, actions: [AlertableAction], completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
}

extension Alertable where Self: UIViewController {
    func presentAlert(title: String?, message: String?, actions: [AlertableAction], completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        actions.forEach { action in
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: action.title, style: action.style, handler: { _ in completion?(action.result) }))
        }
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I then simply invoke this method within my `UIViewController` any time I would like to present an alert

```
   self?.presentAlert(
        title: nil, message: "Are you sure you want to logout?",
        actions: [
            AlertableAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, result: false),
            AlertableAction(title: "Yes", style: .destructive, result: true)],
        completion: { result in
            guard result else { return }
            self?.viewModel.revokeSession()
        }
    )
```

I am trying to assert within a `XCTestCase` that clicking **Yes** calls the correct method on my view model.

I understand a `UITest` will allow me to test the alert is visible and perhaps then on tapping **Yes** I am redirected to the logout route, however I am really interested in testing the method itself.

I am not sure how to test this in code however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to assert within a XCTestCase that clicking Yes calls the correct method on my view model ... I am really interested in testing the method itself.

It actually remains unclear what precisely you are wishing to test. Figuring that out (what actually needs testing?) is most of the battle. You know that `result` is `true` when the title is Yes, so there is no need to test anything about the actual tapping on this particular alert. Perhaps what you are asking to test is just this:

```
    { result in
        guard result else { return }
        self?.viewModel.revokeSession()
    }
```

In other words, you want to know what happens when `result` is `true` vs. what happens when it is `false`. If that's the case, just replace the anonymous function by a real function (a method):

```
func revokeIfTrue(_ result:Bool) {
    guard result else { return }
    self?.viewModel.revokeSession()
}
```

And rewrite your `presentAlert` to take that method as its completion:

```
self?.presentAlert(
    title: nil, message: "Are you sure you want to logout?",
    actions: [
        AlertableAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, result: false),
        AlertableAction(title: "Yes", style: .destructive, result: true)],
    completion: revokeIfTrue
)
```

Now you've broken the function off into something that is independently testable.

Answer (score 0):

Using [ViewControllerPresentationSpy](https://github.com/jonreid/https://github.com/jonreid/ViewControllerPresentationSpy), your test can say

```
let alertVerifier = AlertVerifier()
```

to create the verifier. Then call your `presentAlert` function. Next, call

```
alertVerifier.executeAction(forButton: "Yes")
```

to execute the given action. Finally, call the captured closure:

```
alertVerifier.capturedCompletion?()
```

and verify the expected result.